# Why is my mouse disappearing at runtime?

Tags: unity, mouse

I'm using Unity 5.3.5f1 and every time I play my game in the editor, my mouse disappears. I really need to test some of my parameters in the inspector but I can't because the mouse is gone. How can I fix this, and if possible, make it permanent?

Comment: do you have something like `Screen.showCursor = false;` or `Cursor.visible = false;` in any of your scripts?

Comment: No. However I just tried to to the opposite (set it to true) but it didn't work

Comment: This is a new project, made it this morning. I have another project from a few months ago, however that one does show the cursor.

Comment: I've just discovered something interesting. I made a new project and the cursor was visible, however I added a standard assets first person controller, and sure enough, there goes the mouse.

Comment: Found it, under the Mouse Look section of the First Person Controller script was a checkbox which said 'Lock Mouse'. As soon as that was unchecked all was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the First Person Controller from the standard assets. Just had to uncheck this: First Person Controller script > Mouse Look > Lock Mouse